# Run JQuery once per browser session

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function (a preload screen) that is triggered by page load on the homepage only.

The issue is that it runs every time the user goes back to the homepage.

I've been looking at using sessionStorage to get this function to run once per browser session, however I'm pretty new to JQuery and cannot work out where it goes/what it actually needs to say.

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Here's my code…

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onload = function () {
    $('#loader-wrapper').addClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

Comment: remove that window.onload line (and closing bracket) ...

Comment: Cookies may help. 1) check if the cookie exists (2) if it does exist, do nothing (3) if it does not exist, set a cookie and continue with one-time code.  However, cookies can persist beyond the browser session, you can set their expiration time.  You can also look into localstorage options.

Comment: @Doug cookies can be manipulated if not done properly and thus, are generally seen as a security threat

Comment: @treyBake I guess, kind of ... but the security threat is if you're storing sensitive info in them (and even then that threat isn't that threaty).  Something like `visitCookie = true` I don't see the security threat there.  Either way, just offering up a suggestion on a way to track a homepage visit -- I was just throwing out cookies because that's where I started a dozen years ago :P but there are other local storage options for jlan to try out

Comment: @Doug tis a valid point! It's more a risk with sensitive data etc., as a rule, I just choose to avoid where pos and stick to localStorage :)

Comment: Ideally I would like to avoid using cookies, as then I need to start looking at implementing a cookie warning!

Comment: Definitely not trying to sway you towards cookies. Always pick the right tool for the job and/or the tool you're most comfortable with. But to add something to the warning idea; it's not looked to cookies. If you're storing any unique data, by GPRD you need to ask for consent. If you're using local storage for something non-unique then you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

To run this once per session, use the following to store that the user has already done this during the current session:

```js
$(function() {
  var visited = sessionStorage['visited'] || false;
  if (visited) {
    $('#loader-wrapper').addClass('hidden');
  } else {
    sessionStorage['visited'] = true;
  }
});
```

It might be more efficient/simpler to add the `hidden` class to the div by default (in the HTML) and only remove it if it's their first visit:

```js
$(function() {
  var visited = sessionStorage['visited'] || false;
  if (!visited) {
    $('#loader-wrapper').removeClass('hidden');
    sessionStorage['visited'] = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Can I ask, is this in addition to what I currently have or instead of?

Comment: @jlan155 instead of. You don't need all the on ready, document stuff really. The `$(function () {...` is a shorthand for that. The only part I've lifted from your example is `$('#loader-wrapper').addClass('hidden');` which now gets called if it's the first visit for that session.

Comment: @jlan155 - looking at some other comments from you, this may be the wrong way round... are you looking to hide the div if it is NOT their first visit?

Comment: That's right, so it should show on your first visit and then not again for the rest of the time you're on the site. If you close the browser and navigate back to the site again you should expect to see it again.

Comment: @jlan155 - I see - I've made an edit. You might be better off adding the `hidden` class to the div and only removing the class if it's their first visit...

Answer (score 0):

You should just write:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loader-wrapper').addClass('hidden');
});
```

But your question about running this only once per browser session doesn't make sense for me. You want your function to be executed on your page load. The `$(document).ready(...)` only runs the function once, and only when the DOM is loaded. It won't run later when the user interacts with the page (unless of course it triggers a page reload with a click).

Comment: I've taken out the window.onload line and tested again. When I navigate to another page via the menu and then come back to the homepage I see the preload page again (which is something I only want to see when I open the site in the browser for the first time). I guess its triggering a page reload like you said?

Comment: This is a strange requirement. Since addClass('hidden') would only hide the element the first time the page is loaded if you trigger this only once per session. The DOM is not cached in browser or in the session. Every time you access the page, the `#loader-wrapper` element will be visible again.

Comment: Ah no! Okay so I'm looking at this wrong then. What I'm currently doing is using CSS + JQuery to hide a div on page load to get a fade out preloader…

Can I still do it this way if I only want the page loader to be visible (and then fade out) once per browser session?

Told you I was new to this…